# Using two API Key on Swagger Security Scheme with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, swagger

Is it possible to have two API Keys on Swagger and give them different privileges in my API?

For example:

```
API_KEY_1 : Has access to one Post method
API_KEY_2 : Has access to all of my API
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Spring Security, that all depends on how you authenticate the API keys in your application. Once you've set up the application to validate an API key and create a `SecurityContext`, your best bet would be to map to one of two different roles, one for limited access, and one for all access. For example:

```java
    @Configuration
    public static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    // ...
                    .authorizeRequests()
                            .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/some/api").hasAnyRole("BASIC", "ADMIN")
                            .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN");
        }

    }
```

More information and examples of authorization can be found in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#servlet-authorization-filtersecurityinterceptor).